# create a zoom image ... feature

Tags: google-apps-script, google-maps-static-api

I make one simple example using Google Apps Script and google maps .

The problem if I add many locations : for example one in Europe and another in USA the google static maps show me all the world.

So I need to make a zoom features to deal with this issue .
Thank you . Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`StaticMap.setZoom()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/maps/static-map#setZoom%28Integer%29) method to set the appropriate zoom level on your map

Comment: can be done with 2 buttons to make one function and show dynamical like in google maps zoom ?

Comment: Yes, you can add two buttons , a + and a - which zoom in or out